# Create NSString Url with QueryString

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsurl

I wanna create string something like I mean wanna create url with querystring

NSString *urlString = @"http://*.com/*.aspx?log="+txtMail.text+"&pass="+txtPass.text;

but i'm getting invalid operand to binary expression NSstring in nsstring. any body help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're very new to Objective-C.  Objective-C is not the same as C++.

The line of code you want to use is:

```
NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://.com/*.aspx?log=%@&pass=%@", txtMail.text, txtPass.text];
```

You'll also likely need to percent escape your urlString to create a legal URL, which you can do via:

```
NSString * escapedUrlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: yes Micheal very new.. I m coding .Net Objective C is very strange to me for now.. :) thanks for helping

Comment: Shouldn't the calls to `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` be done on `txtMail.text` and `txtPass.text` and not the whole URL?

Comment: why not the whole URL string (in which case it'd be one call, versus two separate calls to "`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`")?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Actually, neither approach works like I expected. If a user were to enter something like `foo&bar=zzz` into `txtMail.text`, the resulting URL would not be properly escaped. The URL would end up with the extra `bar` parameter. I would hope the value `foo&bar=zzz` would be escaped to `foo%26bar%3Dzzz`.

Comment: The trick here is you need to escape *components* of the URL query. `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` doesn't have enough context to know what you want. Instead, drop down to `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()` and explicitly tell it to escape `&` and `=` characters for you. There's plenty of open source about for this, too.